Intermittent Error "An unknown error has occurred" (Code: 1) when Calling Facebook Graph API
I'm experiencing an intermittent issue when calling Facebook Graph API endpoints from my server and localhost using the Node Facebook SDK. The error message I receive is:
Error:
Message: "An unknown error has occurred."
Code: 1
There's any more useful information in the error nor in the response headers.
This error happens sporadically and, when it occurs, it can last for several hours or even days. I’m unable to reproduce it consistently.
**Interestingly, when I make the same API calls through Postman or the Graph API Explorer, everything works fine without any errors.
**
Has anyone encountered this issue before or have insights on why this might be happening? Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot or resolve this would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!
I inspected the facebook error response searching for any more information about the error, but there's any

This happens to me with different requests. See an example:
https://graph.facebook.com/v20.0/campaign-id-example/adsets?fields=optimization_goal%2Cpromoted_object&access_token=xxxx

If the API itself can't give you anything more than "unknown error", then it is probably not much likely, that anyone here can tell you much more about it either.

maybe someone has experienced something similar and has figured it out
